# How do you create an endpoint in salesforce that accepts files (csv)?

Tags: apex, integration, apexrest

I would like to create an apex service in salesforce that accepts csv files.

Resolved this issue with the following:

Created a public site which the FileUpload class is added. Since I need to create an unauthenticated endpoint.
You can also have the authenticated endpoint via creating connectedApp and setup oauth.

Apex service

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/api/FileUpload/*')
global with sharing class FileUpload{

    @HttpPost
    global static void processFile() {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        Blob b = req.requestBody;
        // Add data processing here based from Blob value
    }
}
```

Client command:

```
curl -H 'X-PrettyPrint: 1' -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' --data-binary '@<file absolute path>' '<public site URL>/services/apexrest/api/FileUpload/'
```

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/232356/ability-of-apex-rest-services-to-accept-50mb-file-how-is-the-heap-size-calculat

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can upload the csv as Content Version, by making a post request using REST api to this particular url "/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/ContentVersion", and have a trigger for Content version object and call your particular class in that trigger to process the csv.

here is the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/ContentVersion) for your reference