# Apex Heap Size and Variable Scope

Tags: apex, governorlimits

I run the following code in the anonymous apex window. As you can see the `accounts` variable was declared inside an IF block.
I output a debug outside of the IF block and the heap size was still showing the same number as it was inside the IF block.

My questions are:

1. Why was the heap size not 'cleared' even though the accounts variable was not accessible anymore beyond the IF block?
2. Why is the "Maximum heap size" limit shown as 0?
3. Is setting the variable as null (to reduce the heap size?) a best practise?

```java
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
if (true) {
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account];
    System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
}
// System.debug(accounts);  Variable does not exist: accounts
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
```

This is the output:

```
|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|1047
|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|4346177
|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|4346177
|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
  Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
```

Notice that the heap size is still the same as previous (inside the IF block).
If I set the `accounts` variable to null, the heap size is going back to close to the original size:

```java
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
if (true) {
    List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Name FROM Account];
    System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
    accounts = null;
}
System.debug(Limits.getHeapSize());
```

Output:

```
|USER_DEBUG|[1]|DEBUG|1049
|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|4346177
|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|1061
Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
```

Thanks.

Comment: Since the Apex runtime is Java it doesn't surprise me that data lingers. Java uses garbage collection so data is only deleted when there are no (strong) references to it and the garbage collector is executed. How the Apex runtime handles variable declarations (and therefore the scope of references) comes down to the Apex "compiler", something only Salesforce Apex PMs and developers will have any details of. In addition, it is only these folks who will know if/when the garbage collector is explicitly invoked in Apex execution flows (it *might* be executed before getHeapSize, but I don't know).

Comment: My answer to your question #3 is a firm "no". There's no need for this, even if scopes are a little wider than they appear in the Apex code, the garbage collector will still deal with the data.

Comment: I would also say that it is quite feasible that the `if` block is optimized away by the compiler. To test this properly you should ensure such optimization is not possible by making the function part of an Apex class and invoking that with a boolean parameter used as the condition of the `if`.

Comment: For #1 & #2: Heap size checks are performed according to certain heuristics, meaning they are not performed on evaluating each statement. Hence, the inconsistent numbers. Check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162050/apex-heap-size-and-limit-confusion) & [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127424/does-execute-anonymous-from-developer-console-not-enforce-heap-size-limit/138318#138318). Also, check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213671/is-heap-size-a-global-limit-that-is-shared-by-all-executions-within-a-transactio/213675#213675) out.

Comment: Also, check Josh Kaplan's comment [here](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kzOTAAY) about heap walks being expensive (One reason why they wouldn't be performed quite frequently). For #3, setting null is neither a good or bad practice IMO, since its context based. But would certainly reduce the heap size. Refer [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328918&type=1&mode=1). You also call `clear` method on a collection to free up the heap consumption.

Comment: BTW, `Limits.getLimitHeadSize()` shows an appropriate value for me.

Comment: If you are simply assigning a variable to null immediately before it goes out of scope this is generally, IMHO, unnecessary and simply adds more code to maintain and understand. Garbage will still be collected at some point. This null assign approach will only help in a very small number of cases where you have significant heap use - and in this case it is probably better to consider how to reduce over-all heap usage than to add such an assignment.

Comment: @arut I don't understand your reference to [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000328918&type=1&mode=1) in support of null assignment, since the knowledge article doesn't consider it.

Comment: @PhilW (a) I should have clarified about the knowledge article in my comment. It doesn't say anything about null assignment, but states the following: `Reduce heap size during runtime by removing items from the collection as you iterate over it`. (b) Agreed that null assignment is unnecessary at all the places and hence, I stated that it should be used based on the context. For heavy heap utilization applications, clearing out the heap might be quite essential. Definitely not required for simple codes, since the apex txn duration as well as heap utilization would be low.

Comment: to confirm above, I wrote a unit test class that does asserts to verify that heap is reclaimed. The test is executed every day in 3 orgs over the span of 18 months; <1% of the time, the test fails and the only explanation is non-deterministic invocation of garbage collector.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments! I guess I just need to make sure that the code is optimised in heavy heap utilisation.